# Multi-Threading/User Feedback in MVVM

Tags: mvvm-light

I am new to MVVM and have written a small app to test the waters and get familiar with the pattern.  The main function of my app takes too long to not have some sort of user feedback that the process is continuing along.   What would be the recommended way to place the call in a separate thread and provide feedback for a progress bar?  The ViewModel code for the function is below.  Thanks for the help.

```
public DataView Data
        {
            get
            {
                return resultsView;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == resultsView)
                {
                    return;
                }
            resultsView = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

    private void SetData()
    {
        Data = RetrieveData.GetPartData(SelectedTeam, SelectedYear).DefaultView;
    }

    public RelayCommand GetData
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Initializers for other part of ViewModel
        // Teams = RetrieveData.GetTeams();
        // Years = RetrieveData.GetYears();

        GetData = new RelayCommand(SetData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely versed on MVVM multi-threading yet, but this link seems quite do-able : [WPF Multithreading: Using the BackgroundWorker and Reporting the Progress to the UI.](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/)
NOW, what I would try is something like this:

```
worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
   Data = RetrieveData.GetPartData(SelectedTeam, SelectedYear).DefaultView;
};
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I ended up doing.  I don't see why that goes against MVVM at all but am still open to opinions.